# How can my users store data using Ethereum-Wrapped Filecoin?

Tags: storage

I'm building a data marketplace and want to have my users store their data (encrypted video, mostly) at their own expense. I can assume that they will have Ethereum available via Metamask, but not Filecoin. To this end, I would like to enable them to upload and store files from the browser at their expense. It seems like EFIL promises a solution, but I can't find any detailed instructions to help me implement. Can anyone recommend a good tutorial on storing data using EFIL, or offer any pointers?